# How to handle (return and parameter) generic types in methods by Visual Paradigm for UML

Tags: templates, methods, uml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

I have got a ClassA and in one of her methods I want to return the genetic type which is chosen at class instantiation of ClassA.
If I have got another class ClassB which inherits from ClassA and defines the generic type from ClassA as a String.
The returned type of the inherited methods from ClassA should switch from `<T>` to `String` automatically.

How can I do this with Visual Paradigm?

[image]